# How to stack layers (slope, curvature, aspect, etc) derived from DEM to form multi-band images in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, layers, dem, pixel

Made a DEM from Landsat imagery and derived the aspect, slope, curvature, TWI, etc layers (generic flood conditioning factors). I now need to incorporate these layers and feed them to a LSTM neural network.

I'm very new to QGIS, and have very little knowledge - so I couldn't try anything that can combine all these layers into one single multi-band image.

Currently thinking of following this procedure:

All the conditioning factors to be stacked together to form a multi-band image.
Each pixel and its neighboring pixels in a 3 × 3 window to be extracted, and 9 pixel vectors to be sorted into a sequential data based on spatial continuity.
The sequential data is sent to LSTM network.
How do I complete step 1?

Comment: Please decide which software you want to work with.

Comment: @Erik done. I'll use QGIS

Comment: Have you made yourself familiar with the [raster calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html#raster-calculator)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Since ArcGIS and QGIS are different platforms, Questions which do not specify a platform are effectively two questions. In addition, your Question ought to answer the questions "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?"

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what LSTM requires but a 4 band image can be build with https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html.

```
gdalbuildvrt -separate four_band_dem_derivative.vrt aspect.tif slope.tif curvature.tif twi.tif
```

As a following step the virtual raster can be converted into GeoTIFF with gdal_translate

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff four_band_dem_derivative.vrt four_band_dem_derivative.tif
```